# modifying html iframe tag style to jquery mobile type style

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a iframe which shows a page from an external source in my page's div. I would like to change the style in which the contents of the page are shown to a jquery-mobile type of style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately thats not possible, the browsers work with iframes as if these are different tabs, so they have a different set of javascript and css files.

The only thing you could do is using js access the iframe and execute some js over it to make it include your own css. The problem with this approach is that browsers doesn't allow you to communicate with an iframe unless they share the same domain... and from what you say thats not the case...

You have more info about cross domain communcations here:

http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Comment: Is there a way to access the elements of the iframe using jquery ?
Yes the page in iframe is from an external source

Comment: Im sorry but f it is an external source you wont be able to access its elements